# Subscribe for outlook events from VSTO Add-In

Tags: event-handling, office-2007, visual-studio-addins

I need to interact with outlook in a way that, when a task is deleted in outlook, I get notice about and if the task has the text "HELLO" in it's body, show a MessageBox.

My add in is in VSTO 2005, and it's for Office 2007.

The only way I see to accomplish this is to subscribe for the Outlook events but after a couple hours in google, my investigation isn't near to a solution.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Well after a couple time in Google I find the one that I look for

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/d22810d9-3bab-4825-a54f-a05244c7f819/

over there the answer was simple, characterize a specific folder and subscribe for it's moving event

Clever answer, works fine for me.